# Where to put the data file in SQL*Loader based concurrent program in oracle apps?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, oracle-ebs

I am trying to upload csv data in Oracle EBS table.

SQL*Loader based concurrent program provides the option. I need to know that can I put the csv data in user's file location or should I put it in the same location where the control file is kept ( eg, in oracle file location (bin))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place both control file and csv in bin directory of custom top and define concurrent executable and concurrent program.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about EBS, but - generally speaking, as SQL*Loader is an operating system command prompt utility, in order to run it

- its directory (`BIN`, right?) should be in `PATH` environment variable so that you could *call* it from anywhere, or
- you have to change current directory into `BIN`

As of the data file you'd like to load, it can be anywhere, in any directory accessible to you. Why? Because you specify its location using the control file's `INFILE` parameter. So, yes - it can be in a directory current to you at the time of invoking `SQLLDR.EXE`, or it can be in any other directory - just specify it in `INFILE`.